# problem playing songs via the spotify web api and javascript

Tags: javascript, spotify

I am working on building a web-based application that interfaces with spotify.  I started with C# and had no problem accessing the API, pulling my playlist and pulling tracks off of it but it seems you cannot play songs with the spotify Web API located here:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/

I then started looking at the Web Playback API located here:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/

I intend to write most of it in c# because my c# is much stronger than my javascript.  The c# piece is working.  I can get an authorization token, pull my playlists and tracks.  I intend to pass this information to the javascript.

I pulled the below javascript from the spotify developer page.  I only kindof understand it so I don't know why it isn't working.  Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

```
<script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>

<script>

window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
  // You can now initialize Spotify.Player and use the SDK
};

const play = ({
  spotify_uri,
  playerInstance: {
    _options: {
      getOAuthToken,
      id
    }
  }
}) => {
  getOAuthToken(access_token => {
    fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play', {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({ uris: [spotify_uri] }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${myaccesstoken}'
      },
    });
  });
};

play({
  playerInstance: new Spotify.Player({ name: "..." }),
  spotify_uri: 'spotify:track:7xGfFoTpQ2E7fRF5lN10tr',
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr: Working snippet at the bottom of this answer!**

---

You do this

```
play({
  playerInstance: new Spotify.Player({ name: "..." }),
  spotify_uri: 'spotify:track:7xGfFoTpQ2E7fRF5lN10tr',
});
```

outside of the following.

```
window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
  // You can now initialize Spotify.Player and use the SDK
};
```

Which means `play` is getting called right away without waiting for the Spotify Web Playback SDK to load. As the comment says `Spotify.Player` can be used as soon as the `onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady` was called.

---

Another problem is that you actually never created a Spotify Connect device. Which is needed in order to use the Spotify Web API to control that exact device. This works by calling `connect` on the `Spotify.Player` instance. In order to know when `connect` is done and the player is ready to play songs you need to define a listener first as shown in the following.

```
player.addListener('ready', ({ device_id }) => {
  console.log('Ready with Device ID', device_id);
});
```

So you actually need two different Spotify APIs in order to achieve your goal. First you need the Spotify Web Playback SDK in order to create a Spotify Connect device (Spotify docs refer to it as player). Afterwards you can control this exact Spotify Connect device using Spotify's Web API.

---

The following snippet will play the song.

**WARNING: This will play music within your browser without any control elements!**

This snippet needs an access token which can be obtained [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/) by clicking the green button saying `Get Your Web Playback SDK Access Token`. The token then needs to be copy-pasted into line 11 of the snippet replacing `<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE>`.

**index.html**

```
<!-- Load the Spotify Web Playback SDK -->
<script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>

<script>
  // Called when the Spotify Web Playback SDK is ready to use
  window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {

    // Define the Spotify Connect device, getOAuthToken has an actual token 
    // hardcoded for the sake of simplicity
    var player = new Spotify.Player({
      name: 'A Spotify Web SDK Player',
      getOAuthToken: callback => {
        callback('<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE>');
      },
      volume: 0.1
    });

    // Called when connected to the player created beforehand successfully
    player.addListener('ready', ({ device_id }) => {
      console.log('Ready with Device ID', device_id);

      const play = ({
        spotify_uri,
        playerInstance: {
          _options: {
            getOAuthToken,
            id
          }
        }
      }) => {
        getOAuthToken(access_token => {
          fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=${id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({ uris: [spotify_uri] }),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`
            },
          });
        });
      };

      play({
        playerInstance: player,
        spotify_uri: 'spotify:track:7xGfFoTpQ2E7fRF5lN10tr',
      });
    });

    // Connect to the player created beforehand, this is equivalent to 
    // creating a new device which will be visible for Spotify Connect
    player.connect();
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @David.  It didn't work for me but I think I am close.  <br/>
The page loaded but was blank.  I replaced YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE with my access token.  I did not provide the device id as the documentation stated that if not provided it would play on whatever device was active.  <br/>
In the console I received a 403 error (Forbidden) with the url:  <br/>
https://api.spotify.com/v1/melody/v1/check_scope?scope=web-playback  <br/>
When I clicked the url I received a 401 error, no token provided.  <br/>
Thoughts?  <br/>
Thank you - Greg

Comment: The page being blank is the correct behaviour. I would suggest to use the snippet as I posted it. So just keep the ```device_id``` parameter. Sounds like you didn't use the link I posted to get the token but used your own piece of software to retrieve it. In this case you need to make sure you have the following scopes included. ```streaming```, ```user-read-birthdate```, ```user-read-email``` & ```user-read-private```.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you!  You were right, I needed to get the token from the link you provided.  The authorization token I received didn't work.  I thought it would as, once I receive it, I am able to access my playlists, tracks etc and pull the information but perhaps that token is only good for the WEB API and not the WEB PLAYBACK SDK.  Thanks again.

Comment: As I said. The token received by your app should work as well you simply need to make sure to have the required scopes included as mentioned in my previous comment. I am glad I could help! Would you mind accepting/upvoting my answer?

Comment: Did you try using the access token from your own piece of software? As I said this should work as well using the required scopes.