# Cannot authenticate to Web Playback API with authorization code flow

Tags: javascript, authentication, token, spotify

I would like to use the authorization code flow to authenticate with the Web Playback API. Unfortunately the playback does not work properly. My browser plays a couple of seconds and then skips all the tracks.

Using the temporary code [from the docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/#authenticating-with-spotify) works fine though.

I obtain the access_token via a server which connects to the Web API and redirect the callback to my client which should connect to the Web Playback API.

I found this question: [problem playing songs via the spotify web api and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880305/problem-playing-songs-via-the-spotify-web-api-and-javascript) and the answerer suggested that an authorization code should work.

This is the server code to connect with the Web API:
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example of the Authorization Code flow with Spotify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      #login, #loggedin {
        display: none;
      }
      .text-overflow {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="login">
        <h1>This is an example of the Authorization Code flow</h1>
        <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary">Log in with Spotify</a>
      </div>
      <div id="loggedin">
        <div id="user-profile">
        </div>
        <div id="oauth">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="obtain-new-token">Obtain new token using the refresh token</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script id="user-profile-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h1>Logged in as {{display_name}}</h1>
      <div class="media">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <img class="media-object" width="150" src="{{images.0.url}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Display name</dt><dd class="clearfix">{{display_name}}</dd>
            <dt>Id</dt><dd>{{id}}</dd>
            <dt>Email</dt><dd>{{email}}</dd>
            <dt>Spotify URI</dt><dd><a href="{{external_urls.spotify}}">{{external_urls.spotify}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Link</dt><dd><a href="{{href}}">{{href}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Profile Image</dt><dd class="clearfix"><a href="{{images.0.url}}">{{images.0.url}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Country</dt><dd>{{country}}</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script id="oauth-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h2>oAuth info</h2>
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Access token</dt><dd class="text-overflow">{{access_token}}</dd>
        <dt>Refresh token</dt><dd class="text-overflow">{{refresh_token}}</dd>
      </dl>
    </script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function() {

        /**
         * Obtains parameters from the hash of the URL
         * @return Object
         */
        function getHashParams() {
          var hashParams = {};
          var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
              q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
          while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
             hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
          }
          return hashParams;
        }

        var userProfileSource = document.getElementById('user-profile-template').innerHTML,
            userProfileTemplate = Handlebars.compile(userProfileSource),
            userProfilePlaceholder = document.getElementById('user-profile');

        var oauthSource = document.getElementById('oauth-template').innerHTML,
            oauthTemplate = Handlebars.compile(oauthSource),
            oauthPlaceholder = document.getElementById('oauth');

        var params = getHashParams();

        var access_token = params.access_token,
            refresh_token = params.refresh_token,
            error = params.error;

        if (error) {
          alert('There was an error during the authentication');
        } else {
          if (access_token) {
            // render oauth info
            oauthPlaceholder.innerHTML = oauthTemplate({
              access_token: access_token,
              refresh_token: refresh_token
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
                headers: {
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                },
                success: function(response) {
                  userProfilePlaceholder.innerHTML = userProfileTemplate(response);

                  $('#login').hide();
                  $('#loggedin').show();
                }
            });
          } else {
              // render initial screen
              $('#login').show();
              $('#loggedin').hide();
          }

          document.getElementById('obtain-new-token').addEventListener('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: '/refresh_token',
              data: {
                'refresh_token': refresh_token
              }
            }).done(function(data) {
              access_token = data.access_token;
              oauthPlaceholder.innerHTML = oauthTemplate({
                access_token: access_token,
                refresh_token: refresh_token
              });
            });
          }, false);
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js (via Node.js)

```
var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
var cors = require('cors');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var client_id = 'MY_ID'; // Your client id
var client_secret = 'MY_SECRET'; // Your secret
var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback'; // Your redirect uri

/**
 * Generates a random string containing numbers and letters
 * @param  {number} length The length of the string
 * @return {string} The generated string
 */
var generateRandomString = function(length) {
  var text = '';
  var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
};

var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
   .use(cors())
   .use(cookieParser());

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

  var state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(stateKey, state);

  // your application requests authorization
  var scope = 'streaming user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state';
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {

  // your application requests refresh and access tokens
  // after checking the state parameter

  var code = req.query.code || null;
  var state = req.query.state || null;
  var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/#' +
      querystring.stringify({
        error: 'state_mismatch'
      }));
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);
    var authOptions = {
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      },
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
      },
      json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        var access_token = body.access_token,
            refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

        var options = {
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          json: true
        };

        // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(body);
        });

        // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
            refresh_token: refresh_token
          }));
      } else {
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            error: 'invalid_token'
          }));
      }
    });
  }
});

app.get('/refresh_token', function(req, res) {

  // requesting access token from refresh token
  var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;
  var authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')) },
    form: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: refresh_token
    },
    json: true
  };

  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      var access_token = body.access_token;
      res.send({
        'access_token': access_token
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log('Listening on 8888');
app.listen(8888);
```

This is the client code to connect with the Web Playback API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Spotify listener</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
        console.log("The Web Playback SDK is ready. We have access to Spotify.Player");
        console.log(window.Spotify.Player);
      };
      async function getToken() {
        /**
         * Obtains parameters from the hash of the URL
         * @return Object
         */
        function getHashParams() {
          var hashParams = {};
          var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
                  q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
          while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
            hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
          }
          return hashParams;
        }
        var params = getHashParams();
        access_token = params.access_token;
        refresh_token = params.refresh_token;
        error = params.error;
        if (error) {
          alert('There was an error during the authentication');
        } else {
          if (access_token) {
            // render oauth info
            console.log("Success ac: " + access_token)
            return access_token;
          }
        }
      }

      async function waitForSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKToLoad () {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          if (window.Spotify) {
            resolve(window.Spotify);
          } else {
            window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
              resolve(window.Spotify);
            };
          }
        });
      }

      async function waitUntilUserHasSelectedPlayer (sdk) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          let interval = setInterval(async () => {
            let state = await sdk.getCurrentState();
            if (state !== null) {
              resolve(state);
              clearInterval(interval);
            }
          });
        });
      }

      (async () => {
        const { Player } = await waitForSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKToLoad();
        const token = "TEMPORARY_TOKEN";   //working temporary token
        //const token = await getToken();  //I get a token but it does not work
        console.log("token: " + token);    
        const sdk = new Player({
          name: "Web Playback SDK",
          volume: 1.0,
          getOAuthToken: callback => { callback(token); }
        });  sdk.on("player_state_changed", state => {
          // Update UI with playback state changes
        });  let connected = await sdk.connect();
        if (connected) {
          let state = await waitUntilUserHasSelectedPlayer(sdk);
          await sdk.resume();
          await sdk.setVolume(0.5);    let {
            id,
            uri: track_uri,
            name: track_name,
            duration_ms,
            artists,
            album: {
              name: album_name,
              uri: album_uri,
              images: album_images
            }
          } = state.track_window.current_track;
          console.log(`You're listening to ${track_name} by ${artists[0].name}!`);
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The debugger shows the error: "TypeError: this._acmeTrack is null"

Any help, hints and of course your time is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using the token with the Spotify Dashboard and see if the token itself is valid for that call, if it is then you might have an error in your code but can at least check if the Token is the issue first

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't exactly understand your suggestion. How/Where can I check the token with the Spotify Dashboard?

Comment: Never mind it's **working** now without changing anything.

Comment: Sure, have posted an answer explaining how to check a token if useful in future or to anyone else!

Answer (score 0):

Handy way to check tokens are working is to go to  [developer.spotify.com](http://developer.spotify.com/) then **Console** and find any authenticated API call you need to try out then you can paste the token you have and if that works, you at least know a token is valid before spending time figuring out what's wrong!